# PowerPoint export to video mangles audio

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint

I am exporting a PowerPoint presentation to Full HD. The presentation is 20 mins long, has 20 slides, has audio voiceover on each slide and has a soundtrack that plays all the way through. I am finding that on some slides the generated video replays snippets of the voiceover and also chops certain words and endings off. I have checked the .mp3 audio files for the .MP3 audio files in question using Audacity and also WMP and they are perfect in both - yet they still get mangled when I do the export? Does anyone have ideas on how to fix this, or some other way of generating the HD video?

Comment: Replaying of the audio snippets could be that you need to de-select the "Loop until Stopped" checkbox (Select the embedded audio and then open the "Playback" tab).  Similarly, its possible your audio is being clipped because you do not have "Play Across Slides" selected.

Comment: Ended up using .wav files and that solved it for me.